# What is the battery weight of the Nissan Leaf 62 kWh?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, batteries, battery-chemistry

I found many websites as [this one](https://qnovo.com/inside-the-battery-of-a-nissan-leaf/) where all details regarding battery packs for 24, 30 and 40 kWh batteries of Nissan Leaf models are stated, while I could not find information regarding the battery weight of 62 kWh model.

Battery weight of 40 kWh model is done according to the battery module weight and number of modules, which is 8.7 kg x 24 = 208 kg. Since number of modules is different regarding newer Leaf model, does anyone know how to properly scale its weight?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: call a Nissan service location

Comment: @BruceAbbott  I am interested in thermal parameters of the battery

Comment: What does the weight tell you about the thermal parameters?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a valid question for this EE site.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PUSHEVS](https://pushevs.com/2020/04/04/comparison-of-different-ev-batteries-in-2020/), the specs of the 40 kWh and 62 kWh batteries are:-

```
40 kWh battery

Total battery capacity: 39,46 kWh
Usable battery capacity: 36 kWh (91 %)
Battery weight: 303 kg
Battery energy density: 130 Wh/kg
Cells: 192 (96s2p)
Chemistry: NCM 523
Manufacturer: Envision AESC
TMS: passive air cooling


62 kWh battery

Total battery capacity: 62 kWh
Usable battery capacity: 56 kWh (90 %)
Battery weight: 410 kg (estimation)
Battery energy density: 151 Wh/kg (estimation)
Cells: 288 (96s3p)
Chemistry: NCM 523
Manufacturer: Envision AESC
TMS: passive air cooling
```

If these figures are accurate then the weight scales up by ~87% of the capacity. However this may just be an artifact of how the 62 kWh battery weight was *estimated*.

Another (possibly less accurate but more reliable) measurement could be taken from the difference in curb weights between the 40 kWh and 62 kWh models, which is 1729 kg - 1573 kg = 156 kg more for the SV+ vs SV. Based on that the 62 kWh battery is 51% heavier, so it scales at 98% of the capacity (ie. almost 1:1).

Answer (score 0):

For rough thermal calculations, such as lump sum temperature rise, I would trust a linear scaling:

$$62 \, kWh \times \frac{208 \text{kg}}{\text{24 kWh}} = 547 \,kg$$

**FYI**: An EV's battery pack is actually over-rated in its nominal capacity to sustain lifetime performance. For example, the 24 kWh battery pack may actually contain 48 kWh worth of battery cells.

When the car is brand new and all cells are fresh (100% rated capacity), the battery management system (BMS) will only permit the car to "use" half the cells. As these cells degrade and lose capacity over time, the BMS will "unlock" more cells for use by the powertrain.

This ensures a nominal 24 kWh over the lifetime of the battery pack.